# How to measure the distance between two points follow the track?

Tags: qgis, distance, road

I have three points shapefile and 1 line shapefile. I tried to use v.distance but it only got directly distance.

How can I measure them by track?

[image]

Comment: possible dupliated https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/207409/calculating-distance-travelled-along-track-in-qgis